# On inf and sup of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

My question is following

Let $(x_{n})$ be a positive sequence and satisfies the inequalities

$\frac{1}{K+x_{n+1}}\leq x_{n}\leq \frac{1}{e^{-v}+x_{n+1}}$

where $K>1$ and $v>0$. How to find inf $x_{n}$ and sup $x_{n}$?

My try: Iterating the given inequalities I have found upper and lower bounds for $x_{n}$ as follow

$$
\frac{\sqrt{K^{2}+4Ke^{v}}-K}{2Ke^{v}}\leq x_{n} \leq \frac{\sqrt{K^{2}+4Ke^{v}}-K}{2}.
$$

But I am not so sure whether they are inf and sup?

Comment: Do you know something about $x_0$?

Comment: @AbdullahUYU. Using given inequalities we can show $x_{n}\leq \frac{1}{e^{-v}+\frac{1}{K+x_{n+2}}} $. Then we can continue this inequaity for infinite level

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I know only $x_{0}\in (0,1)$